# Using data line widths in bokeh

Tags: plot, bokeh

Is there a way to provide line width in bokeh in data space, or alternatively can the line width be fixed in a way that zooming does not alter it? 
I am trying to draw lines right next to one another without clashes or gaps between them.
Currently, I am using a mapping from line width to coordinate width and change the line widths and line coords in sync to achieve this, but as soon as I zoom the line width is adapted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to provide line width in bokeh in data space

No, but feature requests are welcome!

> can the line width be fixed in a way that zooming does not alter it?

Line width is set in screen units - zooming does not alter it by default.

It seems like the problem is that you change your line width in response to the range changes, and zooming does change ranges.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up! Indeed the zooming does not change the line width (on the screen) however it does occupy a different space in terms of the current data range. I don't change any of the line widths in response to the zoom (but maybe I should).

Comment: @Paul Also, computing the line width yourself is not trivial since it would also depend on the angle of the line. Given your needs, it seems that you're better off by drawing the line manually with rects or polygons.

Comment: I wanna do this with a lot of lines (10k-100k) and was hoping to use WebGL. Rects and polygons are not available for that. The angle problem should be handled if I adapt coords and width simultaneously (as i do now), but of course that seems computationally expensive for zooming .. Anyhow thanks for the insights, I think i'll leave a feature request tonight.